# glm rotation does not according to model's new orientation

Tags: game-engine, glm-math, vulkan

I want to achieve camera rotation around an object, however when i rotate the camera in different directions then apply more rotation, the model rotates with respect to it's initial orientation not the new orientation I don't know if I am missing anything or not, how can I resolve this issue?

my MVP initialization

```
ubo.model = attr.transformation[0];
ubo.view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
ubo.proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(50.0f), extend.width / (float)extend.height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
ubo.proj[1][1] *= -1;
```

my update code

```
while (accumulatedTime >= timeFPS)
{                   
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        exit = true;
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && leftMouseButtonPressed == false)
    {
        prev.x = event.button.x;
        prev.y = event.button.y;
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        leftMouseButtonPressed = true;
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP && event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
    {
        leftMouseButtonPressed = false;         
    }
    if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && leftMouseButtonPressed == true)
    {

        New.x = event.button.x;
        New.y = event.button.y;

        delta = New - prev;

        if(delta.x != 0)
            ubo.view = glm::rotate(ubo.view, timeDelta * delta.x/20, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        if (delta.y != 0)
            ubo.view = glm::rotate(ubo.view, timeDelta * delta.y/20, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        prev = New;

    }

    accumulatedTime -= timeFPS;
    v.updateUniformBuffer(ubo);
}

v.drawFrame();

}
```

my vertex Buffer

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

  ....

void main()
{
    gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4 (inPosition, 1.0);
    fragTexCoord = inTexCoord;
    Normal = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4 (inNormals, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: in your example the camera looks around, my objective is to move the camera around the object (like that of a modeling program) i want to achieve this by rotating the object itself to simulate the camera movement for this purpose i changed the order of your matrix equation but still it rotates around the object with respect to its initial orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out i was missing some essential parts of vector rotation, my conclusions are as follows:-

1. We need to have four vectors **cameraPos**, **cameraDirection**, **cameraUp**, **cameraRight** (the latter two vector are the up and right vectors relative to the camera orientation)
2. Each time we rotate our camera position we need to keep track of the **cameraUp** and **cameraRight** vectors (we need to rotate them as well; this was the part that i was missing)
3. The final camera orientation is calculated from the newly transformed **cameraPos**, **cameraUp** and **cameraRight** vectors

You can find a good tutorial about this in [Here](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera)